# Ubuntu - Caffe Installation: Catching Polymorphic Type in layer_factory.cpp

Tags: ubuntu, installation, caffe

I am trying to install Caffe (CPU only version) on my virtual Ubuntu machine and I'm having trouble with the Python Layer (layer_factory.cpp file). I have the following system information:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64-bit)
- Python 3.8.2
- OpenCV 4.3.0

I followed the instructions exactly like explained here https://qengineering.eu/install-caffe-on-ubuntu-18.04-with-opencv-4.1.html (without CUDA or CUDNN). When I am trying to do the "make all" command in the caffe-master directory I get the following error:

```
nina@nina-VirtualBox:~/caffe-master$ make all
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
...
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Layer<Dtype> > caffe::GetPythonLayer(const caffe::LayerParameter&) [with Dtype = float]’:
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:304:1:   required from here
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:298:5: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘struct boost::python::error_already_set’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
  298 |   } catch (bp::error_already_set) {
      |     ^~~~~
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Layer<Dtype> > caffe::GetPythonLayer(const caffe::LayerParameter&) [with Dtype = double]’:
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:304:1:   required from here
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:298:5: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘struct boost::python::error_already_set’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.8m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:596: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

The error is thrown in the following part of the layer_factory.cpp file:

```
#ifdef WITH_PYTHON_LAYER
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetPythonLayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  Py_Initialize();
  try {
    bp::object module = bp::import(param.python_param().module().c_str());
    bp::object layer = module.attr(param.python_param().layer().c_str())(param);
    return bp::extract<shared_ptr<PythonLayer<Dtype> > >(layer)();
  } catch (bp::error_already_set) {
    PyErr_Print();
    throw;
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with this please? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing

`catch (bp::error_already_set)`

to

`catch (bp::error_already_set&)`

Seems to be a general solution --> rather catching exceptions by reference than by value.